# Interrupting pselect when it's waiting - multithread

Tags: c, multithreading, signals

So, according to manual, `pselect` can have a timeout parameter and it will wait if no file-descriptors are changing. Also, it has an option to be interrupted by a signal:

```
sigemptyset(&emptyset);    /* Signal mask to use during pselect() */
res = pselect(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, &emptyset);
if (errno == EINTR) printf("Interrupted by signal\n");
```

It is however not obvious from the manual *which signals are able to interrupt pselect?*

If I have threads (producers and consumers), and each (consumer)thread is using pselect, is there a way to interrupt only one (consumer)thread from another(producer) thread?

Comment: `if (errno == EINTR)` <<-- you should only test errno if pselect() returns -1. In other cases its value is basically undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think the issue is analyzed in **https://lwn.net/Articles/176911/**

> For this reason, the POSIX.1g committee devised an enhanced version of
>   `select()`, called `pselect()`. The major difference between `select()` and
>   `pselect()` is that the latter call has **a signal mask `(sigset_t)`** as an
>   additional argument:
>
> `int pselect(int n, fd_set *readfds, fd_set *writefds, fd_set *exceptfds, 
>                   const struct timespec *timeout, const sigset_t *sigmask);`

`pselect` uses the `sigmask` argument to configure which signals can interrupt it

> The collection of signals that are currently blocked is called the
>   signal mask. Each process has its own signal mask. When you create a
>   new process (see Creating a Process), it inherits its parent’s mask.
>   You can block or unblock signals with total flexibility by modifying
>   the signal mask.

source : https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Process-Signal-Mask.html

https://linux.die.net/man/2/pselect

**https://www.linuxprogrammingblog.com/code-examples/using-pselect-to-avoid-a-signal-race**

Because of your second questions there are multiple algorithms for *process synchronization* see i.e. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/introduction-of-process-synchronization/ and the links down on this page or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sleeping_barber_problem and associated pages. So basically signals are only one path for IPC in linux, cf [IPC using Signals on linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11133887/ipc-using-signals-on-linux)

Comment: For the first, thanks. but for second: I need something which can interrupt threadA's pselect from threadB while not interrupting threadC (or threadC's pselect).

Comment: if it is strictly defined which processes communicate with each other you can use IPC sockets for this https://opensource.com/article/19/4/interprocess-communication-linux-networking and https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX_local_inter-process_communication_socket

Comment: "signals are only one path for IPC in linux" - sure, the only reason for signals is interrupting pselect. If I could interrupt it anyhow else I prefer not using any signals

Comment: No interrupting pselect using signals is good, however for implementing producer-consumer IPC signals are not the first choice (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48381628/how-to-implement-producer-consumer-using-processes), so possibly mix the IPC mechanisms ?

Comment: yes, possibly, but I it just don't feel right. I might drop pselect for some more modern approach (libevent or libev). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

(Ignoring all the signal's part of the question, and only answering to

> If I have threads (producers and consumers), and each (consumer)thread
>   is using pselect, is there a way to interrupt only one
>   (consumer)thread from another(producer) thread?"

, since the title does not imply the use of signals).

The easiest way I know is for the thread to expose a file descriptor that will always included in the p/select monitored descriptors, so it always monitor at least one. If other thread writes to that, the p/select call will return:

```
struct thread {
    pthread_t tid;
    int wake;
    ...
}

void *thread_cb(void *t) {
    struct thread *me = t;
    t->wake = eventfd(0, 0);
    ...
    fd_set readfds;
    // Populate readfds;
    FD_SET(t->wake, &readfds);
    select(...);
}

void interrupt_thread(struct thread *t) {
    eventfd_write(t->wake, 1);
}
```

If no eventfd is available, you can replace it with a classic (and more verbose) pipe, or other similar communication mechanism.